# Lifecycle method once component is rendered

Tags: reactjs

I need to use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the exact location of a particular element once the component is completely rendered.

Which lifecycle method do I need to use for this? I don't think `componentDidMount()` is called after the rendering is completed.

For more clarity, here's what I'm trying to achieve:
My component renders a list of `DIV` elements. There could be as many as 30-40 of them. Once they're rendered, I want to automatically scroll to a particular element. This element could be at the bottom, in the middle or anywhere in the rendered section. I ID each `DIV` element so it's easy to tell `getBoundingClientReact()` to give me its location. Once I get that data, I will scroll to that location.

UPDATE:

This is what my code looks like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

    // Get the ID of the element I need to scroll to
    const id = "divId-" + prevProps.myId;

    // Find the rendered element
    const element = document.getElementById(id);

    // Get coordinates
    const position = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Call scrollTo custom function to scroll to the element
    scrollTo(position.top);

    // Set the new location
    this.props.actions.setLocation(position.top);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `setLocation` basically sets the new location in the Redux store. What's the best way for me to set the new location once I figure it out? Basically, I figure out the new location in `componentDidUpdate()` as part of my code.

Comment: > Note that you cannot call this.setState() here; nor should you do anything else (eg dispatch a redux action) that would trigger an update to a React component before componentWillUpdate returns. Use componentWillReceiveProps() if you need to update state in response to props changes.

Comment: I hope this helps you.

Comment: Definitely very helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentWillUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`

> componentWillUpdate() is invoked immediately before rendering when new
>   props or state are being received. Use this as an opportunity to
>   perform preparation before an update occurs. This method is not called
>   for the initial render.

or 
`componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`

> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component
>   has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as
>   long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a
>   network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

may work for you. You can check detail on [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

Comment: I tried both and I'm getting `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. For some reason, it seems to go into a loop.

Comment: @Sam I think there is a infinite recursive loop or something like it. Would you please write down the code that makes error?

Comment: `this.props.actions.setLocation` function may contain `setState()` and this makes infinite loop. Because `componentWillUpdate()` and `componentDidUpdate()` are executed before and after `setState()` of every component.